# python-mode 6.0.12 indent after return or pass

Tags: python, emacs, mode

I use python-mode in emacs.
I have been using for 1 month with no problems.

Now I have a problem, in that whenever I 'return' or 'pass' a function inside a class, the indent returns to the start of the next line

EG

```
class test(object):
    def method1(self):
        return 1
|cursor returns here, cant press tab to indent
    |cursor should be here, tab should allow free indentation
```

If I dont return or 'pass', i have no problems. I don't know what has caused this.

my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'lambda-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lambda-mode 1)
(setq lambda-symbol (string (make-char 'greek-iso8859-7 107)))

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.0.12") 
(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.0.12")
(require 'python-mode)
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

my .emacs.d contains:
lambda-mode.el python-mode.el-6.0.12 auto-save-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce with trunk. 
If possible, please check it out.

bzr branch lp:python-mode

Exists a mirror at github too.

Bugs are filed preferably at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Answer (score 1):

In the default `python-mode` that comes from Emacs (i.e. `python.el` as opposed to `python-mode.el`), I cannot reproduce your problem.  So maybe you're using `python-mode.el` and could simply switch to the builtin `python-mode` instead.

Comment: Yes I am using python-mode6.0.12.el as stated in the title. the default python mode doesnt even autoindent at all so of course that problem wouldn't happen

Comment: Hmm... the default does auto-indent when I try it (but I don't use Python so I get fooled easily ;-), so maybe you should report a bug that it doesn't work in your case (that's only useful if you use Emacs-24, tho, since earlier versions had a completely different python.el which was lacking maintainer).

Comment: oh, I'm only using emacs 23.3.1, should I try emacs-24?

Comment: Then please report a bug (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) with precise steps to reproduce the problem.